# javascript: how do I fix a 'not a function' error in an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I converted a simple javascript function into one that uses a prototype.  Now a call in an anonymous function is getting the "not a function" error.

From some researching, I see the value of 'this' may not always be what you think it is when an anonymous function is used.

So, how do I fix this problem?

Here's the cut-down code to show the problem.

```html
var chart;

chart = function Chart(){
    var xScale;
}

chart.prototype = {

  method1 : function() {
    this.xScale = d3.time.scale();
  }

  method2 : function () {

    this.xScale(0);  // No "not a function error here"

    // but I get the "not a function" error below when I call this.xScale(d.date)

    var overlay = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function (d) { return this.xScale(d.date); })
      .y0(0)
      .y1(height);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you call  `method1`  on the object created from `Chart` before you call `method2` on it?

Comment: And you're sure it's not the secons call to `this.xScale` inside D3 that triggers the error, as `this` most certainly isn't `chart` inside the callback for `d3.svg.area().x(callback)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the call to `d3.svg.area().x()`, `this` is, most likely, referring to the `area` object. If you want to use your `function(d){}`, it is easiest to just create another variable referring to your current object outside of this call:

```
method2 : function () {
    this.xScale(0);  // No "not a function error here"

    // store the current this here
    var thisChart = this;

    var overlay = d3.svg.area()
      .x(function (d) { return thisChart.xScale(d.date); })
      .y0(0)
      .y1(height);
}
```

By the way, as t.niese suggests, it's not a good idea to rely on `method1` begin called before `method2`, to ensure that `scaleX` is defined.